# Remove Image href border

Tags: html, css

I don't know what I am doing wrong...
I added a css

```
a:active {text-decoration: none; border: 0px solid black}
a:link {text-decoration: none; border: 0px solid black}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; border: 0px solid black}
a:hover {text-decoration: none; border: 0px solid black}
```

But this does not work in IE...
I keep getting this:

[image: Chrome & IE]

The lower one is IE.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of IE?

Comment: Have you tried setting `outline:none;` ?

Comment: Why are you not using border:none ?

Comment: Stupid question, but are the two highlighted imgs inside the same `<a>`?

Comment: No but the problem is already solved, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a style like:

```
a img {border:0;}
```

Should fix it as the border is on the image not the a

Answer (score 2):

if you use image please add this css in your stylesheet.

```
a img {
border:0;
}
```

OR

```
 a img {
    border:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
a img {border:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need the "solid black".

```
border: 0 none;
```

There are two possible things that might cause your problem:

(1) Some browsers recognize another meta-selector:

```
a:focus {text-decoration: none; border: 0 none;}
```

(2) Another thing is that the purple thing might actually be an outline of the links.

Try adding also

```
outline: 0;
```